# access vba docmd.applyfilter for dates

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

I am running a code based on a week number to filter for work order dates that match the week column and are greater than the WODate Column.  My code gives me a "Syntax" Error for the second applyfilter command.  Is there a way to have both filters apply at once?
my code:

```
Private Sub Weeks_AfterUpdate()

    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Week] = '" & Me.Weeks & "'"
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[WODate] >= #" & Format(wodate, "mm/dd/yyy") & "# and [FYDate] <= #" & Format(todate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"

    Me.FilterOn = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss a **y**, and the date separators should be escaped:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[WODate] >= #" & Format(wodate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# and [FYDate] <= #" & Format(todate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
```

Comment: Thank you, but this still gives me a syntax error in date in query expression. and the filter is not applying that portion of the code as a result.

Comment: If the fields are of data type _DateTime_, and the variables actually hold date values, the syntax is correct. Perhaps your fields are text?